# Google Maps Ajax New Markers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I have a google api3 map. On idle, I calculate the radius of the visible area of the map, perform an ajax request and retrieve all of the markers in the visible area from an xml document.

Then I parse the xml, clear the current map markers and replace them with the new markers.

This works, with two caveats. 1) All of the markers flash when reloading. and 2) This causes me to download and reload markers, even if the user did not move the map far enough for them to be off-screen. In other words, I am reloading a marker that is already on the screen.

What is the best way to pull only the markers in the visible area of the map, and aren't already on the screen?

I am going for performance, because I have a large amount of markers.

Test Url: http://whosopennow.com/maintenance/test.php# (Pan to Washington, DC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the map bounds do not include the International Date Line, or map wraps (you might have to set minimum zoom to 4 or so), I would take the following steps using `map.getBounds()` (not tested):

1. At all times store the existing visible bounds. I'll call it `lastViewable`.
2. When the visible bounds are detected to have changed, perform the Ajax call.
3. For each marker in the XML, if it's outside `lastViewable`, add it to the screen. These are the new markers.
4. Now, let's say the map was dragged. Markers now outside the viewable area need to be removed.
5. Set `lastViewable` to the current bounds
6. Remove all markers outside these `lastViewable` bounds.

Comment: However, this still requires me to download those extra markers in the xml document, and then skip them using javascript. I don't want to have them in the xml at all in order to minimize time between loads.

Comment: Can you have server-side do the processing (decide which markers were inside the last displayed bounds)? Then send back only new markers.

Comment: Yes, but this would require me to make an extra server call sending the server the id's of all the markers onscreen, effectively doubling my load time.

Comment: No, you just send the SW/NE bounds to the server like I described, and have the server throw out duplicates. I do see the problem that with my scheme removing old markers can only be done with JavaScript.

Comment: We will try that. Is there a faster way to send data about the markers instead of creating, downloading, and parsing an xml document?

Comment: JSON? I'm not familiar with any security risks with it but I do know it's fewer bytes (in most cases).